# Case-sensitive pattern in `less -i` for single search

Tags: regex, less

I’d like to perform a one-time case-*sensitive* search in `less -i` for a pattern that contains only lowercase letters (so SmartCasing does’t work here).

For example, in some flavors of regex, it would be: `(?c)something-lowercase`

My use case is that 99% of the time my searches need to be case-insensitive, but every once in a while, case matters, and the string I’m searching for is all lowercase.

Note that I’m looking for a purely regex solution without having to resort to turning `-i` off temporarily.

Comment: Case sensitive setting looks like `(?-i)`. Try putting it in front of the pattern.

Comment: Just tried that — no luck

Comment: Then you should not use PCRE tag, this regex library allows the use of inline modifiers.

Comment: Some PCRE modifiers in less work. Example: `(?i)`

Comment: If the `\ban\b(*SKIP)(*F)|a` does not remove all `a`s not inside `an` word, it is not PCRE.

Comment: `-i/something-lowercase^M-i` seems a fairly minimal number of characters to add to the regex

Comment: If you build `less` from source, you can configure it to use one of several regex libraries. I use `./configure --with-regex=pcre2`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, I might have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After checking that `less --version` shows `less 590 (PCRE2 regular expressions)`, I believe it’s a bug that `less -i` ignores `(?-i)`. I’ve filed a [ticket](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/197).